# Edit flutter BasicTimeField

Tags: flutter

I added in my code this class:

```
class BasicTimeField extends StatelessWidget {
final format = asd.DateFormat("HH:mm");
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(children: <Widget>[
    Text('Basic time field (${format.pattern})'),
    DateTimeField(
      format: format,
      onShowPicker: (context, currentValue) async {
        final time = await showTimePicker(
          context: context,
          initialTime: TimeOfDay.fromDateTime(currentValue ?? DateTime.now()),
        );
        return DateTimeField.convert(time);
      },
    ),
  ]);
}}
```

And it is taken from this website:

https://pub.dev/packages/datetime_picker_formfield

I want to change the heights and border-radius of the time popup but I don't know from where I can do this. Where can I customize all the details of the widget?

Comment: That's system dialog, you can't customize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the dart_picker_dialog.dart file of the package. But it is not recommended as they mentioned in that comment line.

```
       // Constrain the textScaleFactor to the largest supported value to prevent
      // layout issues.
      final double textScaleFactor = math.min(MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor, 1.3);
```

Later, the textScaleFactor will be used to calculate the dialogSize.

```
          final Size dialogSize = _dialogSize(context) * textScaleFactor;
```

For more, you can look [here](https://github.com/jifalops/datetime_picker_formfield/blob/master/lib/datetime_picker_formfield.dart).

Comment: Thank you so much!!